# Displaying 'Not Found' error after successfully deploying on Heroku with Git

Tags: angular, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I'm a fresher who is trying to deploy an angular project on Heroku. Now I have tried several times to deploy this project on Heroku with Git. When I deploy it says it is successful but when I open the app, it says 'Not Found'. I will share the work I did.

server.js file

```
 const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/application-reminder'));
app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+
    '/dist/application-reminder/index.html'));});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "application-reminder",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "v14.17.4",
    "npm": "6.14.14"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Here's what is on build log in Heroku when deployed

```
  -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  v14.17.4
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.14.14
       
       Resolving node version v14.17.4...
       Downloading and installing node 14.17.4...
       npm 6.14.14 already installed with node
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_a9017a0d/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents
       > node install.js
       
       
       Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported
       
       > nice-napi@1.0.2 install /tmp/build_a9017a0d/node_modules/nice-napi
       > node-gyp-build
       
       
       > esbuild@0.12.17 postinstall /tmp/build_a9017a0d/node_modules/esbuild
       > node install.js
       
       
       > core-js@3.16.0 postinstall /tmp/build_a9017a0d/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > @angular/cli@12.2.3 postinstall /tmp/build_a9017a0d/node_modules/@angular/cli
       > node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
       
       added 1321 packages in 25.588s
       
-----> Build
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > application-reminder@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_a9017a0d
       > ng build --prod
       
Option "--prod" is deprecated: No need to use this option as this builder defaults to configuration "production".
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
- Copying assets...
✔ Copying assets complete.
- Generating index html...
✔ Index html generation complete.
       
       Initial Chunk Files               | Names         |      Size
       main.19a598aa2682e8109fac.js      | main          | 214.63 kB
       polyfills.2f8af3457401605bcf37.js | polyfills     |  36.22 kB
       runtime.6f604d1d25b6cea174c8.js   | runtime       |   1.04 kB
       styles.31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c.css   | styles        |   0 bytes
       
       | Initial Total | 251.89 kB
       
       Build at: 2021-08-27T08:45:46.131Z - Hash: b7e425376bd69dc2cceb - Time: 41651ms
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       removed 924 packages and audited 396 packages in 12.796s
       
       28 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 70.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v3
       https://application-reminders.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

And after all of that, I only get a 'Not Found' error on the screen.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible to share the url?

Comment: Try to edit `index.html` file in your dist folder `/dist/application-reminder/index.html`. Change `<base href="/">` to  `<base href="./">`

Comment: @RiteshWaghela Yes, Here's the Git repo link: https://github.com/rushLovenshier/application-planner

Comment: @smithnblack I don't quite understand what you mean. I don't know where the list folder is. -.-